# How to use Custom SiteMapProvider in ASP NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, web-config, sitemapprovider, security-trimming

I am currently trying to implement a Custom SiteMap Provider. I have read several tutorials about it, and followed their lead.

I have created a subclass of XmlSiteMapProvider named MySiteMapProvider which is located in MyProject.Security.

I have added the following code to the system.web section of my Web.config:

```
 <siteMap defaultProvider="MySiteMapProvider" enabled="true">
        <providers>
            <add name="MySiteMapProvider"
              description="Custom SiteMap provider."
              type="MyProject.Security.MySiteMapProvider "
              siteMapFile="Web.sitemap"
              securityTrimmingEnabled="true" />
        </providers>
    </siteMap>
```

But I am sure that my Provider is not used correctly. I couldn't even start with the implementation. To verify that I have included the following (pseudo) implementation:

```
 public override bool IsAccessibleToUser(System.Web.HttpContext context, System.Web.SiteMapNode node)
    {
        Debug.Print("Hello World");
        throw new Exception();            
        return base.IsAccessibleToUser(context, node);
    }
    public override void Initialize(string name, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection attributes)
    {
        Debug.Print("Hello World");
        throw new Exception();     
        base.Initialize(name, attributes);
    }
    public override SiteMapNode BuildSiteMap()
    {
        Debug.Print("Hello World");
        throw new Exception();     
        return base.BuildSiteMap();
    }
```

But I can use the site and navigate as much as I want to, no Exception comes up and the Debug console shows no Hello World at all.

Did I forget something important?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of implementing my own Provider, I went along with the [MvcSiteMapProvider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider). 
The customization of the behaviour that I needed to implement was realized in one day with dynamic sitemaps and a custom SiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider.

I also considered implementing the whole SiteMapProvider, maybe on SQL basis, and I am glad that I did not have to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `System.Web.SiteMap.RootNode` from code.

Comment: Alright that executes my code. But it only makes the check for the root node. And it is only executed when this specific piece of code is called. So how would I go further?